# Raw SQL in Typeorm Where Find Options

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, typeorm

```
await this.newsRepository.findAndCount({
        select: {
          id: true,
          publishedAt: true,
          isDisplayed: true,
          priority: true,
          availableTo: true,
          availableFrom: true,
          useAvailablePeriod: true,
        },
        where: [
          {
            status: NewsStatus.PUBLISHED,
            newsCategories: { seoName: params.categorySeoName },
            useAvailablePeriod: true,
            availableFrom: `< ${new Date()} OR IS NULL`,
            availableTo: `> ${new Date()} OR IS NULL`,
            publishedAt: LessThanOrEqual(new Date()),
          },
          {
            status: NewsStatus.PUBLISHED,
            newsCategories: { seoName: params.categorySeoName },
            useAvailablePeriod: false,
            publishedAt: LessThanOrEqual(new Date()),
          },
        ],
        order: { publishedAt: 'DESC', priority: 'DESC' },
      });
```

How can I use a similar construction as shown with the `availableFrom` and `availableTo` parameters or something similar in order not to fill in a huge number of array elements in where.

I don't want to use Query Builder. Is there any way to get around `Or` without writing a huge amount of data to the where array?

I tried to write all these `Or` as elements of the where array, but then the where construction is too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md

```
import { Raw } from "typeorm"

const loadedPosts = await dataSource.getRepository(Post).findBy({
    currentDate: Raw((alias) => `${alias} > :date`, { date: "2020-10-06" }),
})
```

will execute following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "post" WHERE "currentDate" > '2020-10-06'
```